# Jenkins pipeline to exit if shell script fails in any stage

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have jenkins pipeline jobs which runs shell scripts internally. even though the shell scripts fails job will show as passed only.

My Pipeline:

```
stage('Code Checkout') {
timestamps {
step([$class: 'WsCleanup'])
echo "check out======GIT =========== on ${env.gitlabBranch}"
checkout scm
}                                     
}
stage("build") {
sh 'sh script.sh'  
}
}
catch(err){
currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
emailExtraMsg = "Build Failure:"+ err.getMessage()
throw err
}
}
} 
LOG:
+ sh script.sh
$RELEASE_BRANCH is empty
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your script returns with zero status code. Otherwise it would throw an exception as described in [`sh` step description](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script). The problem may be that exit status of `sh sctipt.sh` is the exit status of *last executed command* and your script may do something after error happens (e.g. `echo` something before exit). The simplest and brutal way to make sure every error is returned is to use put `set -e` at the top of your script.

You don't need any `catch` to have this functionality (I mean fail on script error) unless you want to do some extra operations in case of error. But if you do, then you should enclose script execution in `try` clause:

```java
stage("build") {
  try {
    sh 'sh script.sh'  
  }
  catch (err) {
    currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
    emailExtraMsg = "Build Failure:"+ err.getMessage()
    throw err
  }
}
```